# top nav text menu won't vertical align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been fooling with this little menu that is going to go inside of a header div. I am not sure what has gone wrong but the only way to get the menu center inside of the header div is by using spans and coding within the spans. I don't really want to use spans as there is a lot of code that seems like a waste. Right now my web page is at:

```
http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index2.html
```

I have made some great progress thanks to this forum. The menu starts at the top of the page with:

```
<p class="hot-menu">Search Tahoe Lakefronts<span>Search West Shore Tahoe    Lakefronts</span><span>Search Squaw Valley Luxury Homes</span></p>
```

I am trying to control it with either a div or a p i.e.:

```
.hot-menu {
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px !important;
    font-family: Lato, Arial, Verdana !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
```

I thought maybe it would center in the nav because the p tag is having some form of control, so I tried a div, still no luck.

I just want it to look like this:

```
http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index3.html
```

Any suggestions? Thanks so much. -Beth

Comment: It may be beneficial for you to consider using an `ul` `li` type of structure for your menu.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you use the `nav` tag and an unordered list structure for this, like **@A. Sharma** suggested in the comments. This will allow better HTML semantics and will be easier to maintain and style.

To achieve what you want there are several methods, including using `transform`, `display: table-cell` or `flexbox`.

In the following code snippet you will find the flexbox solution since I consider it the *easiest/best/modern* solution.

*-- Note: The question does not specify what will happen in smaller devices. You can use CSS media queries to handle this.*

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  /* Illustration purposes only.*/
}
.hot-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
.hot-menu > ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 0 40px;
  display: flex;
}
.hot-menu > ul li {
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-family: Lato, Arial, Verdana;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  /* Illustration purposes only.*/
}
```

```html
<nav class="hot-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Search 1</li>
    <li>Search 2</li>
    <li>Search 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**Test**: Newest version of Chrome.

[image: evidence]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following lines to your navigation class:

```
float: right;
line-height: 60px;
```

This should make it work the way you want it.

Comment: The float element should not be used for formatting.

Comment: Then pack it into a new div and let it float, but why should it not be used?

Comment: I got it to work using Antoines' css addition.  Although, I am clueless as to why the float element should not be used for formatting?

Answer (score -2):

Elements by nature will ignore the `vertical-align` property, unless the element is specified to be a table cell. You can do this by applying `display: table-cell;` on the element, and adding `display: table;` to its parent, like so:

```
.nav_container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_item {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/j0nv3v9e/1/

Comment: Hi There - I added all css Tyler provided and updated the webpage and that one does not seem to work. Any ideas, see:  tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index3.html ?

Comment: Your issue is now unrelated to vertical alignment and moreso along the lines of general CSS/page structure. Personally I would suggest you research `float`ing elements in CSS to position them side-by-side.